# Finding the first letter in a String

Tags: java, string

I have a String

```
String s="#$% AbcD89";
```

And I'm trying to get the first letter of that String regardless of if it's capitalized or not. However, I do not know how many characters are before that first letter. I have tried using

```
int index=0;
outerloop:
for(int i=0; i<s.length;i++) {
    if(Character.isLetter(s.chartAt(i)) { //Tried with isAlphabetic as well
        index=i;
        break outerloop;
    }
}
```

But these return what seems to be a random character. Basically, that doesn't return the first letter

**Note I cannot use Pattern and Matcher classes**

Comment: Is this code part of some bigger code block ? I rewrote your code and other than some compile time errors, it works just as you want it to.

Comment: Yes, essentially I am reading content from a file and putting it as a String. My only problem is that it happens that the file I am trying to read starts with "Ï$%". However, I don't know what's in the other file I have to read (it might be "#$%" or just straight up start with a letter)

Comment: why break outerloop; and not just break?

Comment: do you mind posting the code where you parse this file into the string ? Might help a bit more then. Also, @bhspencer makes a good point. The addition of outer loop is redundant, a simple break statement would suffice.

Comment: @KrabbyPatty I've found where my mistake is! Thanks! I was reading the file with FileInputStream, so I just switched to Scanner and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you are trying to solve a lab-problem? Have you looked at the character encoding? or is those leading characters specified as "there might be non-letters at the start of the string"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this. Note that `0` is a legitimate location as an index so initialize your index to -1 and test before using.

```
String s = "#$% AbcD89";


int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) { 
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (index < 0) {
    System.out.println("No letter found!");
} else {
    System.out.println("First letter is : " + s.charAt(index));
}
```

prints

```
First letter is : A
```